# Internal Server Error when using YouTube API & PHP

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

After months of putting it off I am trying to update [my code](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/webMashups.html) to use Version 3 of the YouTube Data API.

I am in China so I need to use a VPN to work on this code, but the servers are in Atlanta. The line of code that gives me grief is:

```
$this->youtubeService = new Google_YoutubeService($this->googleClient);
```

That actual Google Client creates fine I can print it to the screen. I have blown away the API on the server thinking something went wrong in the upload, [the example code using Books runs](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/test.php), I've enable the API in [my console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/378508349021/apiui/apis/enabled), I put printf's on either side of my code and narrowed it down to this line, but all I know is

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (favouriteQuotationsMashup.php, line 0)

I can comment the line out to keep my code and my site running, but I am really not amused that I keep having to jump through hoops to get APIs to work *again*, YouTube is cool and all but it isn't vital to the function of my website, the only place I use it is in [my quotation mashup](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/favouriteQuotationsMashup.php?q=195). How do I figure out what is causing this error, especially if it is in Google's now giant beta PHP library?

Comment: Take a look at the error log of your webserver, there should be a clean message regarding the problem.

Comment: Just a guess: The class is called `Google_YouTubeService`, (capital `T`), could just be the typo.

Comment: I tried that typo theory. I tried a lot of stuff. Apparently I was too dumb to look at the error log. I'll have a look at that today. I swear I cut and pasted the method call from the official YouTube example, but you know I've seen official examples with mistakes before so I'll triple check typos.

Comment: I have been meaning to fix this for a long time, I plan to take a fresh look at this, this weekend.