# Youtube API response with internal 500

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been using Youtube API with v3 version to get playlist of youtube.

example url:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=xxxxxxxxx

But I found sometime Youtube API response with error message "500 Internal Server Error"

How can I fix or prevent this error from using Youtube API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually comes from the YouTube side. You can refer to the related post about `500 Internal Server Error` and it all point out as an outage to the YouTube.

See relevant post:

- [YouTube Data API v3 - Error 500 getting playlist list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204251/youtube-data-api-v3-error-500-getting-playlist-list)
- [Internal Server Error when using YouTube API & PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176883/internal-server-error-when-using-youtube-api-php)
- [youtube reporting api error 500 internal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304884/youtube-reporting-api-error-500-internal-error)
- [Internal server error from YouTube Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487996/internal-server-error-from-youtube-analytics-api)

Also, it was declared in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) as a failed request due to an internal error.